# How do I access a static variable in my HTML and iterate over it

Tags: angular, typescript2.0

I have to iterate through a static variable.

```
<div *ngFor=" let j= index">
  // code 
</div>
```

I have two loops, the first loop iterates over an i index and the second one iterates over j, so i want j to have unique values, not depending on i. In the current situation j loops from 0 to a specific length and when i gets incremented , j starts with 0 again, but I do not want that, I want j to have unique values.
Is it posssible to achieve it?

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I have two loops, the first loop iterates over an i index and the second one iterates over j, so i want j to have unique values, not depending on i. In the current situation j loops from 0 to a specific length and when i gets incremented , j starts with 0 again, but i do not want that, i want j to have unique values

Comment: if you has an array to make a loop use `{{i*array.length+j}}`

Comment: {{i*array.length+j}} gives an error

Answer (score 0):

with this code `let j= index` you are storing index each time in the loop
you can simply declare a variable and assign static value to it then use it wherever you want
and this is not the right way to write for in angular it should be like 
`*ngFor="let eachOne  of  theNameOfYourArray; let eachIndex= index"`

Comment: eachIndex i can declare in .ts file?

Comment: yes you can declare it in .ts file then assign your static value to it and remove
`let eachIndex= index` from your code

Comment: I tried this way, <div *ngFor= "let testvar = index" and I have declared testvar in my ts file -> static testvar= 1; but it is not working

Comment: look `let testvar = index"`this means to assign index each time to eachIndex don't use this `*ngFor="let eachOne  of  theNameOfYourArray;"` is the right way to loop inside an array
then declare your variable in .ts file
`public NameOfVariable : typeOfVariable = ValueOfIt`